# Bind Drawable Background Color with MVVM light in Xamarin.Android

Tags: mvvm, xamarin, binding, xamarin.android, mvvm-light

I am using MVVM light within my Xamarin.Android project and would like to bind my `MainViewModel`'s `StatusColor` property to the background of a `GradientDrawable` which acts as background of an `ImageView` control.

Unfortunately, a `GradientDrawable` does not have any `Color` property that I could bind my color to, just a `SetColor(int)` method. Is there a way to tell MVVM light to always call this `SetColor(int)` method whenever the `StatusColor` property of my `MainViewModel` changes?

The ugly(!) alternative would be to fire an event when the ViewModel changes the color property, but I really want to avoid that...

My code currently looks like this:

```
// This does not work!
this.SetBinding(
    () => MainViewModel.StatusColor,
    () => ((GradientDrawable)IvStatus.Background).Color); // There is no GradientDrawable.Color property...
```

If it helps, here is my `IvStatus` control and the `Drawable` its background is set to:

**`IvStatus`:**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivStatus"
    android:background="@drawable/Circle"                                    
    android:layout_width="10dip"
    android:layout_height="10dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
```

**`Circle.xml`:**

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#cccccc"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="1dip"
        android:color="#333333"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: I don't think you can. Maybe take a look at the MvvmCross libraries, they may have a binding workaround. But as far as I know for MvvmLight you should just subscribe to the property changed event, in your android app, and manually create a new GradientBrush when the color value changed in your VM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Binding.WhenSourceChanges method.

```
this.SetBinding(
    () => MainViewModel.StatusColor)
    .WhenSourceChanges(() =>
        {
            // This is where you can use SetColor
        });
```